# How to import botbuilder-java into existing Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, botframework

I would like to use the new botbuilder-java SDK from Microsoft allowing to work with Microsoft Teams with Java and more especially with Spring Boot.

The SDK can be found here: [botbuilder-java](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java)

I know this is a preview library. However, I could not find any corresponding maven plugin to import.
So how should I import this SDK into my existing Spring Boot app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, I found out we need to add these entries to the pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-schema</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-connector</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-integration-spring</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-builder</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-dialogs</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-ai-luis-v3</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>bot-applicationinsights</artifactId>
            <version>[4.6.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
```

You may need to set the versions that suit best your needs.

Then what I did is that I copied the implementation of their BotController and put it as Resource (i.e. endpoint controller) in my project so I could change the endpoint name.
You will also need to copy some files from the samples folder to perform the tasks you need.